# Kohana 3.2 error

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Model_Categories' not found
MODPATH/orm/classes/kohana/orm.php [ 37 ]
32  public static function factory($model, $id = NULL)
33  {
34      // Set class name
35      $model = 'Model_'.ucfirst($model);
36 
37      return new $model($id);
38  }
39 
40  /**
41   * "Has one" relationships
42   * @var array
```

im keeping on having this error... i have no idea how to fix it.

after i uploaded it to the shared host, i keep getting this error
i already checked for the following:
1. changed .htaccess RewriteBase and made it

```
RewriteBase /
```

2. Also changed bootstrap.php base_url to "/"
3. Checked Model_Categories and it is visibile in the directory

i dont know the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the file that contains "Model_Categories" is called "categories.php" (lowercase) and is in "application/classes/model"

Windows file system is case insensitive but Linux is not which might explain why it works on your machine but not on the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

exists class / model / categories ? Pay attention to uppercase and lowercase letters in name of file.